# Can a Google Slides App Script be triggered by clock DURING a presentation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Using Google App Script, I have constructed a crude clock to display on a single slide during a worship service.  When I am in edit mode, the display updates every minute by a clock trigger.  When I move to presentation mode, however, the time fails to update until I exit the presentation.

What do I do next to have this trigger function while the slide is "presenting"?

Here is the trigger and the function it calls:

Run:[updateClockText] Events:[Time-driven][Minutes timer][Every minute]

```js
function updateClockText() {   
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    m = checkTime(m);
    var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
    var elements = slide.getPageElements();
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; ++j) {
        var el = elements[j];
        if (el.getPageElementType() === SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE &&
            el.asShape().getLink() &&
            el.asShape().getLink().getUrl() === CLOCK_ID) {
            el.asShape().getText().setText(h + ":" + m);
        }
    }
}

function checkTime(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return '0' + n
  } else {
    return n
  }
}
```

Comment: My hunch is that entering the "present" mode gives you a static version of the file, and any changes to that presentation are not loaded. Consider opening the file in two browser windows, and entering presentation mode in one of them to verify

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I just checked, and it appears indeed to be a static version.  No changes I made showed up in the "Present" mode until after I exited back to edit mode.  Any ideas on how to cause the presentation to reflect updates?  One other method I have tried is to publish the slide with an auto-advance every few seconds, auto-start on load, and restart after the last slide.  This, too, fails to update dynamically.

Comment: Given that the presentation appears to be client side, you can't alter it once launched, except by exiting and restarting the presentation.

Comment: Consider opening a feature request for this capability on the relevant component of Google's public issue tracker.

Comment: We shall see if that generates any discussion.  I cross-posted to the Google App Script community as well [here](https://plus.google.com/106393508974126030187/posts/WNXgzj2mXPs), hoping to get some attention on the issue.  Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Some documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/lifecycle